# Rename column with hyphen

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to rename, in a Oracle database some column who have "-". But, I have an error. I execute :

```
alter table thisTable rename column "dcsplc-a" to UPPER(dcsplc-a);
```

I have this error :

> Error: ORA-23290: This operation may not be combined with any other operation

So, I know "-" isn't a good idea, but I cannot change. I want just uppercase like "DCSPLC-A".

Do you have a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the `UPPER` function.
You have to use hard coded name (and also qualify a name with special characters)

```
alter table thisTable rename column "dcsplc-a" to "DCSPLC-A";
```